# Function cumulative

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which it is running correctly only for the first cell (cell(3,2)).I guess this is due to wrong function code.how can I adjust the Function so as to repeat the cumulative sum not only for the cell (3,2) but for next as well.(3,3), (3,4)etc.

```
Sub check()
   
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
         
    
    For k = 2 To 3
    For i = 1 To 6
       
        If Cells(4, k) <= SumOffset1(i) Then
       
            Cells(5, k) = (i - 1) * 5 + (Cells(4, k) - SumOffset1(i - 1)) / (Cells(3, i + 2) / 5)
           
            
            Exit For
        End If
       
     Next i
       
     
    Cells(4, k + 1) = Cells(4, k) - Cells(4, k).Offset(-1, 1)
   
    Next k
   
    
End Sub
 
Function SumOffset1(iteration As Integer) As Double
    Dim sum As Double
   
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
   
    For k = 2 To 2
    For j = 0 To iteration
   
        sum = sum + Cells(3, k).Offset(0, j)
       
    Next j
    Next k
    SumOffset1 = sum
End Function
```

I want to modify the function in order to repeat the same result not only for the specific starting point cell (3,2) but the same loop to continue for the next cell (3,3),(3,4) etc

Comment: It would continue just fine if you didn't use `Exit For` and start off your i with 1. i = 1 means your first SumOffSet1 goes through it twice (`j = 0 to iteration`) but then if `Cells(4, k) <=` than that result, you'll end up going through it once since i-1 = 0 so the iteration in the function goes once and then immediately after your `Exit For` stops your loop. So either adjust the iteration in your function (or how it's used) or adjust how you use the Exit For (or even how you pass the iteration to the function).